# Link to library target from different subdirectory

Tags: c, cmake

I have the following set-up:

In a folder `lib`:

## lib.h

```
#ifndef LIB_H_
#define LIB_H_

int fun(int i);

#endif
```

## lib.c

```
#include "lib.h"

int fun(int i) {
  return i;
}
```

## CMakeLists.txt

```
add_library(lib SHARED lib.c)
```

In a directory `src`:

## main.c

```
#include "lib.h"
int main () {
  return fun(0);
}
```

## CMakeLists.txt

```
add_executable(main main.c)
target_link_libraries(lib)
```

and finally in their common parent directory:

## CMakeLists.txt

```
include_directories(lib)
add_subdirectory(lib)
add_subdirectory(src)
```

When I try to build my project with

```
cmake
make
```

I get the following linker error:

```
CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `fun'
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the `target` parameter in your call to `target_link_libraries`, it should be:

```
target_link_libraries(main lib)
```